# Preventing login and user creation via federated authentication if criteria is not met

Tags: federated-authentication, azure-ad, owin

I have successfully setup Federated Authentication for the Sitecore client with Azure AD. However we have some additional requirements to meet:

- A user must be within a given AD group to be able to login
- *Valid* users should be persisted, so that roles can be maintained in Sitecore

For a user performing their first login, if the identity's claims are not transformed into a role, Sitecore will inform the user they do not have access. However the user is still created within Sitecore (if persistence is enabled), and if user is then added as a member of a role including client access, they will then have access even if do not meet the AD group requirement.

To accomplish this, looking at other examples outside of Sitecore, I thought the appropriate place for this criteria check would be within the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification:

```
args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    .. other required properties omitted ..

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {                   
        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
        {
            var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            foreach (var claimTransformationService in identityProvider.Transformations)
            {
                claimTransformationService.Transform(identity,
                    new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
            }

            // Must have mapped to at least one role as a result of our transformations.
            if (!identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Role, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException("User must be mapped to at least one role");

            notification.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, notification.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

            return Task.FromResult(0);                      
        }

    }
});
```

Here, we perform our criteria check and throw a `SecurityTokenValidationException`. However, in Sitecore this results in the exception bubbling up and presenting a YSOD, rather than the user being taken back to the login screen and told they failed authentication. Whilst this *is* preventing the login, the experience for the user is bad.

What's the correct way to achieve this?